# Length of anopheles chromosomes?

Tags: chromosome, gene, data

Where can I find the length of each anopheles chromosome? I've obtained data in which the length of each 2L chromosome for several anopheles is 39101648. I'm looking for an article that gives the length of 2L so I know my output is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this [paper](http://ccb.jhu.edu/people/salzberg/docs/Anopheles-gambiae-reprint.pdf) (Holt et al. 2002), does this answer your question? Look at Table 2 and 3. In this paper the lenght of 2L is  52393056 bp.